# Question about open sets: $A \cap B = \emptyset$ implies $\overline{A} \cap \operatorname{int} \overline{ B} = \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be an open set and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. How to prove that $\overline{A} \cap int \, \overline{ B} = \emptyset$? 
 Just use definitions?

Let  $x \in \overline{A} \cap int \, \overline{B}$.  Then  $ x \in \overline{A}$ and $x \in  int \, \overline{B}$.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We proceed by absurd:

Suppose by contrary $\bar{A} \cap \text{int}\bar{B} \neq \emptyset$.

Assume that exist an element $x$ s.t. $ x \in \bar{A}$ and $x\in \text{int}\bar{B}$.

By definition of interior part, exists an **open** set $x \in U \subset \bar{B}$. So $x \in U \cap \bar{A}$.

By definition of closure of a set, $ U \cap A \neq \emptyset$. So exists an element $y$ s.t. $y \in A$ and $y \in U \subset \bar{B}$.

So, $A \cap \bar{B} \neq \emptyset$ then by the definition of closure ($A$ is **open**), $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$.

Absurd

For some references check out the wiki pages for [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28topology%29) and [interior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_%28topology%29)

Answer (score 1):

Since $A\cap B=\emptyset$, you know that $B\subseteq X\setminus A$ which is closed (here, $X$ is the topological space those sets live in). Therefore $\bar{B}\subseteq X\setminus A$ and, setting $C=\operatorname{int}\bar{B}$, also $C\subseteq X\setminus A$. Since $X\setminus C$ is closed, we know also that $\bar{A}\subseteq X\setminus C$.